# Update Form Multiple Select Can't Display Value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a multiple select type control named fruit. When I want to update the fruitcollection form, the value that I entered earlier cannot appear on the fruitcollection multiple select form. What's the solution? Thank you

Update.cshtml (View)

```
...
    <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" name="FruitsCollection" value="@Model.Fruit">
     <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
     <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
     <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
    </select> 
...
```

StoreController.cs (Controller)

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
...
public ActionResult Update(int id)
{
      MasterStore store = new MasterStore();
      if (id!=0)
      {
          store = db.MasterStore.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
          promo.FruitsCollection = promo.Fruit.Split(',').ToArray();
      }
   return View(store);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateStore(MasterStore store)
{
     MasterStore p = db.MasterStore.Where(s => s.Id == store.Id).First();
     p.Id = store.Id;
     p.Fruit = store.Fruit;
}
...
```

MasterStore.cs (Model)

```
...
public partial class MasterStore
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Fruit { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string[] FruitsCollection { get; set; }
}
...
```

Comment: `<select>` elements don't have a `value` attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
         <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
         <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option> 

I added, but still can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your model, you *could* do something like this:

```
<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" name="FruitsCollection">
     <option value="Apple" selected="@(Model.FruitsCollection.Contains("Apple") ? "selected" : null)">Apple</option>
     <option value="Banana" selected="@(Model.FruitsCollection.Contains("Banana") ? "selected" : null)">Banana</option>
     <option value="Watermelon" selected="@(Model.FruitsCollection.Contains("Watermelon") ? "selected" : null)">Watermelon</option>
</select>
```

This part,

```
selected="@(Model.FruitsCollection.Contains("Apple") ? "selected" : null)"
```

will either render as `selected="selected"`, or be omitted - the tag builder omits attributes that are set to `null`.

That's not really going to scale well. You probably would get better results from using the `HtmlHelper` for a multi-select, the [ListBoxFor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listboxfor) helper:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.FruitCollection, 
    /* todo */, 
    new { @class="form-control select2" })
```

You would need to decide how you want to build the required second parameter, where I have the `/* todo */` placeholder. That needs to be an instance of the [MultiSelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.multiselectlist) class, which you can create inline or as part of creating the model within the controller. Here's the bare minimum to do it inline with your values:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.FruitCollection, 
    new MultiSelectList(new string[]{ "Apple", "Banana", "Watermelon" }), 
    new { @class="form-control select2" })
```